# Is it possible to have a base class with a return type that adjusts to the type of the base class?

Tags: c#, generics, derived

Basically my setting is this:

```
public abstract class BaseObject{
    public abstract BaseObject Clone();
}

public class DerivedObject : BaseObject{
    public DerivedObject Clone()
    {
        //Clone logic
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't compile because it isn't possible to change the return type when overriding a method.

Is it possible to achieve that every derived type's Clone method returns an argument of it's own type (maybe through generics)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, C# doesn't allow covariant return types as you've found... but you *can* use generics:

```
public abstract class BaseObject<T> where T : BaseObject<T>
{
    public abstract T Clone();
}

public class DerivedObject : BaseObject<DerivedObject>
{
    public override DerivedObject Clone()
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```

This solution can be a pain in various ways - not least because it's hard to understand - but it can work reasonably well in many situations.

EDIT: The reason I've included the constraint on T is so that `BaseObject` can call "its own" methods on instances of `T`, which is usually very handy. If you don't need this though, you can lose the constraint.

Comment: Could you describe some of the various ways that this solution could be a pain?

I'm trying to figure out whether it's worth to take this pain for the lesser pain of not having to typecast every single time I use the Clone method.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Fixed, thanks. @crischu: Well, there's nothing to say that another class can't derive from `BaseObject<DerivedObject>` for one thing - so it's not foolproof. Also if you have to interact with another type, it can get *really* hairy - in Protocol Buffers I've got `IMessage<TMessage,TBuilder> where TMessage : IMessage<TMessage,TBuilder> where TBuilder : IBuilder<TMessage, TBuilder>` for example. Nasty. It's mostly okay, but you need to keep a cool head.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.  Instead of returning default(T), return something based on the cloning logic.

```
public class MyBase<T>
{
    public T Clone()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}

public class MyDerived : MyBase<MyDerived>
{
}
```

By the way, for object cloning I like to serialize the current object to memory using the binary serializer, then deserialize that memory back into a new instance.